# Passing dynamic data through Angular 2 route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

It is possible to pass static data to an Angular 2 route without showing it on the URL.

But how can I pass **dynamic** data/object in the same way?

Comment: I am assuming you want to pass simple data for UX purpose right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a resolver. The data returned by a resolver is made available to routes the same way static `data` on route configurations is

For an example see https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard

> ```
> @Injectable()
> export class CrisisDetailResolve implements Resolve<Crisis> {
>   constructor(private cs: CrisisService, private router: Router) {}
>   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<Crisis>|boolean {
>     let id = route.params['id'];
>     return this.cs.getCrisis(id).then(crisis => {
>       if (crisis) {
>         return crisis;
>       } else { // id not found
>         this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center']);
>         return false;
>       }
>     });
>   }
> }
> ```

> ```
> path: '',
> component: CrisisListComponent,
> children: [
>   {
>     path: ':id',
>     component: CrisisDetailComponent,
>     canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
>     resolve: {
>       crisis: CrisisDetailResolve
>     }
>   },
> ```

> ```
> ngOnInit() {
>   this.route.data
>     .subscribe((data: { crisis: Crisis }) => {
>       this.editName = data.crisis.name;
>       this.crisis = data.crisis;
>     });
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things
1.Not recommended but use data as router parameter and pass,

```
{ path: 'some:data', component: SomeComonent }
```

and use as

```
let data = {"key":"value"}
this.router.navigate(['/some', data)
```

2.Instead of passing data through route params(because data may be huge and also vulnerable to attack since it can be viwed by the user)

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  data = {};
}

@Component({...
   providers: [SomeService]
export class Parent {
  constructor(private someService:SomeService) {}

  private click() {
    this.someService.data = {"key":"value"}
  }
}
```

Comment: don't you think shared service is overkill for such simple object

Comment: yeah, I consider that but if the object is too large this I prefer.

Comment: @tsadkanyitbarek  is these work for localhost:0000/home/id=2 and localhost:0000/page1/id=2 where id is the static data and id number is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to combine the previous two answers:

- Günter Zöchbauer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41095411/230446) consists of a custom Resolver which is an [message enricher](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DataEnricher.html): Given an URL ending in `/crisis/15`, it will pass the full data of the crisis to the CrisisComponent. We need the Resolver, but I think OP did not want any data to show in the URL.
- Tsadkan Yitbarek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41107138/230446) proposes a service for data storage and communication (similar to a Store in Redux/Flux).  He rightly thinks this is overkill, but we need to store the information somewhere.

The solution therefore is to put the shared data in the Resolver itself: Unlike components, services are long-lived and always have only one instance so the data is safe in the resolver:

```
// --- CrisisDetailResolve --- 
// In the function body, add:
private currentCrisisId: number | string

set(crisisId: number | string) {
   this.currentCrisisId = crisisId 
}

// change line 5 of CrisisDetailResolve:
 let id: number = 0 + this.currentCrisisId

// -- In your code -- 
// You can now navigate while hiding 
// the crisis number from the user:
private click(crisisId : string | number) {
  // tell resolver about the upcoming crisis:
  this.crisisResolve.set(crisisId)  
  // navigate to CrisisDetail, via CrisisResolve:
  this.router.navigate(['/crisisDetail')
  // CrisisDetail can now receive id and name in its NgOnInit via `data`,
  // as in Günter Zöchbauer's answer and the Angular docs 
}
```

See also [Angular Docs on Routing](http://](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards))

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the dynamic data from the Angular7.2 using the state object

In Component send any data using navigateByUrl

```
  public product = { id:'1', name:"Angular"};
  gotoDynamic() {
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/dynamic', { state: this.product });
  }
```

And read it using history.state

```
In dynamicComponent

    ngOnInit() {
           this.product=history.state;
    }
```

Reference:
[Passing Dynamic Data](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-data-to-route/#passing-dynamic-data)